# Overflowing content

Tags: html, css, mobile, overflow

I am trying to create a mobile page that resizes for different devices.
So far so good but I cannot figure out why extra space is being added to the right of the page. I even tried hiding overflow and other hacks.

The issue appears when looking at the page on a mobile device.

Any help?

Here's the page:
http://pages.purolator.com/mobile

Also, there is padding being added as the tab section expands. Can't figure that out either.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from `.pageHeader` and it fixed it.

Try this:

```
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
```

Edit:

This will mess with the padding for your logo. So you will want to add this to your css:

```
.pageHeader img {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I tried to give you an upvote but apparently I am not "reputable" enough . . .